# SHOW SLAVE HOSTS shows incorrect output

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.1

I had used `--report-host` option in one of my slaves, so that I could see that under `SHOW SLAVE HOSTS`. Now that server is no longer in use. I have uninstalled that server as well. Unfortunately I still see the details of that server under `SHOW SLAVE HOSTS`(When this is executed on the uninstalled server's master) which is incorrect.

What changes should I make such that `SHOW SLAVE HOSTS` gives me the correct output?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to check the following items

- If the decommissioned Slave server still has /etc/my.cnf, do one of the following

  - `rm -f /etc/my.cnf`
  - `mv /etc/my.cnf /etc/my.cnf.old`
- If the Master Server still has any `--report-host` in its /etc/my.cnf

  - remove `report-host` from /etc/my.cnf
  - `service mysql restart`
- You may need `service mysql restart` on the Master anyway
- Make sure you delete `master.info` in the datadir of the old Slave

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: I am afraid it did not work.

Comment: Updated my answer...

Answer (score 1):

I find that executing a `FLUSH` command helps in refreshing the `SHOW SLAVE HOSTS` output. It isn't deterministic; I sometimes need to execute two or three `FLUSH` commands, but it certainly refreshes.

I found that either `FLUSH LOGS` or `FLUSH STATUS` do the job.

Comment: Turfing up an old answer here but I had a similar issue where my master was showing slaves that no longer existed (within Kubernetes cluster). Running `FLUSH STATUS` a few times cleared everything up. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I was fighting with the exact same problem in a more intricate replication setup `M1 <-> M2 -> S1 -> S2` where `M1` and `M2` is an active-passive (passive server = read-only) master-master replication setup and `S1` + `S2` are regular slaves chained from `M2` via `S1` to `S2`.

I looked at Rolando's answer which seemed irrelevant to me and I tried Shlomi's answer in several different test setups but couldn't get it working.

In the end I had to study MySQL's source code to find out where data in `SHOW SLAVE HOSTS` comes from and how to "flush" it.
Turns out that when a slave registers to a master it runs `SHOW SLAVE HOSTS` on the master and add that output to its own slave_list hash structure which is used as output for `SHOW SLAVE HOSTS`.

In my case with master-master replication it meant it did not matter what I did locally, I had to reset data at master for it to be refreshed at slave.

To answer this actual question a restart of the MySQL server should clear the output if it's a master -> slave setup and the master itself is not a slave of any other server.

Additionally, if anyone face the same situation as me above with master-master replication here are the steps to solve it:

1. Issue `STOP SLAVE` on both masters (stops replication temporarily).
2. Add `skip-slave-start` to my.cnf (server config file) on both servers. This prevents the slave thread from automatically starting upon restart.
3. Restart mysqld on both servers (e.g. `service mysql restart`)
4. Issuing `SHOW SLAVE HOSTS` on both servers should now give empty outputs.
5. Run `START SLAVE` on both. Each will fetch the other master's empty list to begin with.
6. Remove `skip-slave-start` again from both my.cnf files
7. Now `SHOW SLAVE HOSTS` on both servers should only list active servers.